# Watch Steam stream without having Steam account

Tags: steam, steam-broadcasting

Lately I have used the "broadcast stream" option in Steam to let some friends watch "No Man's Sky", so they could see if it matches their expectations before buying.
They had Steam accounts. I checked "public" option to make my video stream accessible by anyone without me explicitly allowing each one in.

Now my question: If I want to let someone watch my broadcast (Twitch-style) on the Steam webpage without a Steam account... would that be possible somehow?
Or do you need a Steam account before being even able to join a public broadcast?

Thanks for any help on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a Steam account to watch broadcasts. They will however need an account to be able to type in chat.